# Checking length with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried everything that I've found on the site, but none of it's working. I'm trying to say that is the character's in a div are over a certain count, then trigger a function, but it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$("#2").on("click", function () { 
  if($("#1").length > 0) {
    $("#1").html("yes")
  } else{
    $("#1").html("N0")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1">
  12
</div>
    
<div id="2">
  click here
</div>
```

Comment: In addition to DinoMyte's answer, element IDs should not be only numerical.

Comment: @Draco These ids are all within the restrictions of the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): _The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters_

Comment: @Andreas I seem to recall somewhere that a single, numerical, character was not ideal.

Comment: the HTML5 Spec does allow any string of non-space characters BUT both HTML4 and XHTML require `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` As well a proper identifier in Javascript follows about the same rules (no colons or hyphens though). If you specified the HTML5 doctype then it's likely the html engine is not working correctly per the spec. Better to be safe and backwards compatible in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for `.text()` of the element.

`$("#1").length > 0` would check if the occurence of that element is greater than zero ( which in this case is 1 ) -- In other words, if the element exists.

```
if($.trim($("#1").text()).length > 0)
```

Fixed here : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/19spta2h/1/

Comment: +1, but a trim would probably be helpful too, since the OP's original div#1 has a length of `6` from the whitespace characters. `$.trim( $("#1").text() ).length`